# Как отправить TCP-Minecraft пакеты с разными идентификаторами python

Tags: python, сокет, tcp, minecraft

Мне нужно отправить несколько пакетов с разными ID (интендефикаторами) на сервер Minecraft с разным содержимым.

```
1 пакет - ID 0x00
2 пакет - ID 0x03
3 пакет - ID 0x04
```

Как такое сделать?
*Ссылка на документацию - https://wiki.vg/index.php?title=Protocol&oldid=13367*

Comment: А что такое ID пакета ? И как это согласуется с тем, что протокол TCP потоковый, вы сначала устанавливаете соединение (это уже 3 служебных пакета), а потом передаете данные и при этом вы обычно не можете управлять тем, что и как будет собрано в пакеты при передаче

Comment: Тогда почему в документации для подключения к одному серверу написано следущее? ```Packet ID: 0x00 ; State: Login ; Field Name: Name ; Field Type: String (16) ; Notes: Username``` . Как мне добавить Packet ID для правильного подключения? Или я что-то не так понял.

Comment: А можно ссылку на ту доку ? я подозреваю что эти поля где то внутри прикладного протокола там указываются

Comment: https://wiki.vg/index.php?title=Protocol&oldid=13367

Comment: Ну вот там и смотрим. формат пакета, например без сжатия https://wiki.vg/index.php?title=Protocol&oldid=13367#Without_compression  состоит из 3 полей length, packet ID, data. Т.е. длина пакета, id, данные. Если то что надо передать в данных, которые вы показали это десятичные числа, то надо для начала узнать в каком они формате, что бы знать их длину. Сама длина пакета и id указано что имеют тип VarInt, который описан отдельно ....

Comment: https://wiki.vg/index.php?title=Protocol&oldid=13367#VarInt_and_VarLong согласно описанию значения до 127 кодируются одним байтом. значит первый пакет побайтно: 0x03 0x01 0x6E (если число 110 то же VarInt или char, т.е. один байт)

Comment: Так что без указания что это протокол minecraft и собственно ссылки которую вы дали в комментариях ваш вопрос не имеет смысла. потому что обсуждается прикладной протокол на основе TCP, а не сам TCP. так что все эти сведения надо писать в самом вопросе

Comment: От вашего ответа понятнее не стало. 1. Каким образом отправлять пакеты? Отдельно или как-то еще. 2. Как отправить айди пакета. Если я поставлю на отправку 0x01 то меня консоль посылает доить быков. 3. Как закодировать данные, которые отправляются с пакетами. || Вопрос дополнил.

Comment: Отправлять как удобнее. Но сначала устанавливаете соединение (выполняя connect). Потом готовите данные к отправке. Я бы на вашем месте, если нет готовых библиотек реализующих протокол minecraft сделал бы свои функции хотя бы умеющие кодировать VarInt (в документации там примеры даже есть, только на питон перевести). Ну и функцию отправки бы сделал которая принимает 2 параметра: id пакета (число) и данные (bytes). формирует пакет, укладывая опять же байтами подряд VarInt(длина данных), VarInt(id), data и этот массив байт собственно отправляем.

Comment: В вашем случае, если в качестве данных VarInt(110), как я предполагал по первой редакции вопроса (вы сейчас данные убрали из него) то минимально делается `s.send(b'\x03\x01\x6e')`; где s - сокет с установленным соединением, пакет: первый байт собственно длинна (3), второй ID пакета (1) ну и третий один байт данных (110)

Comment: Допустим, я сделал VarInt конвертор, засунул в него некоторый текст, который после конвертации занимает, допустим, 124 байта. Как должен выглядеть код отправки такого пакета?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126927/discussion-between---and-mike).

Comment: VarInt нужен только для того что бы кодировать числа, которые согласно протоколу должны быть именно с таким типом данных. И максимальная длина у них, если вы читали доку, 5 байт. Из обязательных это только поле длины и поле packet id. А вот что у вас внутри данных и как их кодировать это надо смотреть в каждом конкретном случае, согласно спецификации данного типа пакетов. Если вы поле data уже закодировали и оно получилось 124 байта, то отсылаемые данные выглядят как b'\x7e\x00{124 байта данных}', где 0x7e длина данных + 1 байт id + 1 байт длины, если я правильно понял что включает длина

Comment: А, нет, не правильно понял. там 0x7d потому что в несжатом пакете в длину кладется только длина данных + длина поля id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос поставлен *странно*.
С помощью сокетов можно отправлять наборы байтов на целевой сервер.
К примеру пакет с id=x00 будет отправлен таким образом:

```
from socket import socket
mySocket = socket()
mySocket.connect(("127.0.0.1",25565))
mySocket.send(bytes(b'\x10\x00\xf2\x05\t127.0.0.1#\x82\x02'))
```

---

**Разбор 4 строчки(Если надо):**

- \x10 - длинна следующего пакета в байтах (x10 = 16)
- \x00 - id пакета (0)
- \xf2\x05 - версия протокола (тут формать varint. Я значение с лету не
  скажу)
- \t - (python отображает этот байт как символ) длинна адреса целевого
  сервера (проверка на proxy)
- #\x82 - (python отображает первый байт как символ) порт Unsigned Short
- \x02 - сообщение о том, что вы хотите подключится к серверу
- [конец пакета]

---

В начале подключения ничего не шифруется и не сжимается до того, как сервер не отправит пакет id=x03 или id=x01